# Use Python subprocess.check_output() with LC_ALL as first argument

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

from a Python script I want to call a few external programs and use their output inside the script. Now I found that this script is running on my local system, but gets problems on another one that uses another language. So instead of checking the output in different languages, I want to call these programs with a specified "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8" as first argument. But it seems that subprocess does not like this:

```
lc = "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8"
uptimedata = subprocess.check_output([lc, "/bin/uptime"])
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./serverwatch.py", line 22, in <module>
    uptimedata = subprocess.check_output([lc, "/bin/uptime"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I understand that subprocess.check_output() wants the first argument to be the command to be called. So how can I run the command with the changed LC?

This is Python 2.7.3 on Debian Wheezy. The other system is running the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your command through bash:

```
>>> lc = "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8"
>>> command = ["/usr/bin/bash", "-c", "%s /bin/uptime" % lc]
>>> command
['/usr/bin/bash', '-c', 'LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 /bin/uptime']
>>> uptimedata = subprocess.check_output(command)
>>> uptimedata
b' 13:26:01 up 17:43,  1 user,  load average: 0.36, 0.41, 0.44\n'
>>>
```